# C++ Changing operand order when overloading operators

Tags: c++

My problem is in the form **Ax** = **B**, where **A** is a square matrix and, **x** and **B** are vectors. I'm defined a Matrix class and am trying to overload the forward slash operator such that B/A would produce x.

The first line of my overloading function is below:

```
vector<double> Class_A_Matrix::operator/(vector<double> B_Vector)
```

My code works but only if the order of the operands either side of the operator is A/B. How can I adjust my code such that I can do B/A?

Comment: That's incredibly confusing notation. Why on earth wouldn't you write **Ax = y** or something like that?

Comment: change `B_Vector` to `A_Vector` and make sure you have `A_Vector` and `*this` around the right way in your function ?

Comment: note that B/A may have zero or any number of matrix solutions ([see here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorDivision.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define and implement a non-member

```
Class_A_Matrix operator/(const vector<double> &, const Class_A_Matrix &);
```